# Mainframe Jcl proc

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have doubt how to handle rc from proc. Suppose

```
//STEP1    EXEC PROC=BANKEMP
```

How to handle return code from this step using if else .pls provide syntax.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a web reference, here's the [PDF manual](https://www-40.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sa231385/$file/ieab600_v2r3.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for providing me manual.I have checked there and shall I use syntax like this ,pls correct me If I am wrong 

//STEP1    EXEC PROC=BANKEMP

//IF1   IF (STEP1.BANKEMP.RC=0) THEN

//DO SOME PROCESS

//ELSE

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Would you mind deleting your first comment, the one with the wrong link? It is missleading others. And, yes, there is a *web reference* to the [JCL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=mvs-zos-jcl-reference)

Answer (score 1):

## z/OS MVS JCL

### The IF / THEN / ELSE / ENDIF statements

The z/OS JCL IF/THEN/ELSE statements are described in the "*z/OS MVS JCL Reference*",  chapter [IF/THEN/ELSE/ENDIF statement construct](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=reference-ifthenelseendif-statement-construct). These statements can be used to test the termination result of previously executed steps.

From the point of view of z/OS MVS a step has **successfully** completed if:

1. it has really been run
2. it has **not** ABENDed, i.e. the program has proberly terminated and has set a return code. *Note* that the return code value does *not* matter for this decision.

If there was an ABEND, either forced by the system, i.e. the *completion code* is of form "*Shhh*" (where *hhh* is three hexadecimal digits), or issued by the program, i.e. the *completion code* is of form "*Udddd*" (where *dddd* is four decimal digits), the step is considered to have ended **unsuccessfully**.

#### Testing the result of successful step execution

Basically, you can test against the *highest return code* of all previous steps **which have actually been run**, or you can test against the specific *return code* of a **single step that has actually been executed**. Testing against steps which have not been run due to an IF statement, always returns *FALSE* (the step is marked as "FLUSH" in the job log).

If you code an `IF` statement without referring back to a step, or procedure step, you test against the highest return code so far:

```
//IF01     IF   RC EQ 5 THEN
```

If you want to test the return code of a specific step, you code the *step name*, or the *procedure step name* **and** the *step name*:

```
//IF01     IF   STEP01.RC EQ 5 THEN
```

or

```
//IF01     IF   STEP01.PROCST02.RC EQ 5 THEN
```

**Note:** You *cannot* refer back to an `EXEC PROC=` statement, since that statement does *not execute* a program, but merely copied the JCL statements from the procedure into the curent job. Only `EXEC PGM=` statements execute a program, and only programs set a return code.

#### Testing against ABENDs or whether a Step was, or was not run

You can use keywords `ABEND`, `¬ABEND`, `ABENDCC`, `RUN`, or `¬RUN` to test for those step ending states, accordingly. See above manual for more details.

### Sample Prodecure to Play with Return Codes

Here is a sample JCL procedure you can use to play with return codes. *Note* that the first step creates a small REXX procedure that will be called by follow on steps to set a specific return code. Copy this procedure to a member in your JCL library, and name it `RCTEST`:

```
//RCTEST   PROC PROCRC01='0004',PROCRC02='0008'                
//*
//*---------------------------------------------------------   
//*                                                            
//PROCST00 EXEC PGM=IEBGENER                                   
//SYSPRINT DD   DUMMY                                          
//SYSIN    DD   DUMMY                                          
//SYSUT1   DD   *,DLM=##                                       
/* REXX */                                                     
                                                               
/* Test if PARM is a whole number between 0 and 4095 */        
/* If true, set RC to that value, else set RC=12     */        
if datatype( arg(1), "W" )                                     
then do                                                        
  if arg(1) >= 0  &  arg(1) < 4096                             
  then RC = arg(1)                                             
  else RC = 12                                                 
  end                                                          
else RC = 12                                                   
                                                               
exit RC                                                        
##                                                             
//SYSUT2   DD   DISP=(NEW,PASS),DSN=&&REXX(SETCODE),           
//         RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,SPACE=(1,(1,,1)),AVGREC=K         
//*                                                            
//*---------------------------------------------------------   
//*                                                            
//PROCST01 EXEC PGM=IKJEFT1A,PARM='%SETCODE &PROCRC01'         
//SYSTSPRT DD   DUMMY                                          
//SYSTSIN  DD   DUMMY                                          
//SYSEXEC  DD   DISP=(OLD,PASS),DSN=&&REXX                     
//*                                                            
//*---------------------------------------------------------   
//*                                                            
//PRIF01   IF   PROCST01.RC GT 0 THEN                          
//*                                                            
//PROCST02 EXEC PGM=IKJEFT1A,PARM='%SETCODE &PROCRC02'         
//SYSTSPRT DD   DUMMY                                          
//SYSTSIN  DD   DUMMY                                          
//SYSEXEC  DD   DISP=(OLD,PASS),DSN=&&REXX                     
//*                                                            
//PRIF01E  ENDIF
```

Code a job like this to call the procedure, and specify the return codes wanted via `PROCRC01=`, and `PROCRC02=` on the `EXEC` statement. *Note* that you need to adjust the `JCLLIB` with the name of your JCL library (the one you copied the procedure into).

```
//jobname    JOB ....
//***************************************************/       
//*                                                          
//         JCLLIB ORDER=your.jcl.library
//*                                                          
//***************************************************/       
//*                                                          
//STEP00    EXEC RCTEST,PROCRC01='0004',PROCRC02='0006'      
//*                                                          
//IF01      IF STEP00.PROCST01.RC EQ 4 THEN                  
//STEP01    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                 
//IF01      ENDIF                                            
//*                                                          
//IF02      IF RC EQ 4 THEN                                  
//STEP02    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                 
//IF02      ENDIF                                            
//*                                                          
//IF03      IF RC NE 0 THEN                                  
//STEP03    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                 
//IF03      ENDIF                                            
//*                                                          
//*                                                          
//IF04      IF RC EQ 0 THEN                                  
//STEP04    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14                                 
//IF04      ENDIF                                            
//*
```

If you want to play with return codes outside of procedures, you can simply copy the first step from the procedure (`PROCST01`) to your job.

Comment: //STEP1 EXEC PROC=BANKEMP                                                                                                                                                                                    //IF1 IF (STEP1.RC=0)                                                                                                                                                       THEN       ---------->Please confirm the second line syntax @phunsoft

Comment: Not sure what you want me to confirm. You don't show the `BANKEMP` prodecure, so we do not know what steps and stepnames there are in that procedure. You're a bit lazy with providing information. Edit your question and add at least the procedure and a sample job, so we get a base to discuss.

Comment: Thanks @phunsoft for your patience in answering me. I should not enclose the details about proc that's reason I didn't post here. But I got a clue from your last answer. Thanks for it.

Comment: You **cannot** refer back to a `EXEC PROC=` statement, since a `PROC` does not *execute* a program but merely copied the JCL statements from the procedure into the curent job. Only `EXEC PGM=` statements execute a program, and only programs set a return code.